# Changed pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce *changed*?

Its pronunciation is /tʃeɪndʒd/ but I often notice that people don't pronounce dʒ in it. Is it acceptable not to do so?

I often hear tʃeɪn_d without the dʒ sound. Also it becomes difficult to pronounce dʒ in fast speech.

The only thing I can do is to pronounce it as tʃeɪntʃt instead of tʃeɪndʒd. Is this acceptable?

Comment: _Who_ do you hear pronouncing it this way?

Comment: Please qadd a linked reference giving the 'official' pronunciation. Have you checked several dictionaries to see if there are possibly different results of different surveys?

Comment: I don't believe *changed* and *chained* are often pronounced the same way, which seems to be what you're claiming. It will confuse people if you do this. I do think people sometimes pronounce *changed* as /tʃeɪnʒd/, changing /dʒ/ into /ʒ/. Is this what you're hearing?